# Differences in size of std::string_view of non-null terminated char array

Tags: c++, c++17, string-view

I was playing around with *std::string_view* with different compilers and noticed that each compiler prints out different sizes when initializing the *std::string_view* with a non-null terminated char array.

It seems that every compiler prints out the correct size when turning on optimization but prints out the wrong size when optimization is off (except GCC, which prints out the correct size in both cases).

My question is: Why is this the case?

Code:

```
// test.cpp

#include <iostream>

#ifdef __MINGW32__
#include <experimental/string_view>
#elif _MSC_VER
#include <string_view>
#endif

int main()
{
    const char foo[3]{ 'f','o','o' };

#ifdef __MINGW32__
    std::experimental::string_view str_v{ foo };
#elif _MSC_VER
    std::string_view str_v{ foo };
#endif

    std::cout << sizeof(foo) << " " << str_v.size() << '\n';
}
```

Output: Visual C++ 19.00.24619.0

```
3 5 // cl /Zi /std:c++latest /EHsc /nologo /W4 test.cpp
3 3 // cl /O2 /std:c++latest /EHsc /nologo /W4 test.cpp
```

Output: Clang 4.0.0-r282394 (using MinGW-w64)

```
3 4 // clang++ -g --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 -std=c++1z -Wall -o test.exe test.cpp
3 3 // clang++ -02 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 -std=c++1z -Wall -o test.exe test.cpp
```

Output: GCC 6.2.0 (MinGW-w64)

```
3 3 // g++ -g -std=c++1z -Wall -o test.exe test.cpp
3 3 // g++ -O2 -std=c++1z -Wall -o test.exe test.cpp
```

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: As mentioned below, you need to null-terminate the string with '\0', or use a const char* string which is null terminated for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/basic_string_view/basic_string_view):

> constexpr basic_string_view(const CharT* s);
>
> Constructs a view of the **null-terminated character string** pointed
>   to by s, not including the terminating null character.

Your test program causes Undefined Behaviour, as T.C. has mentioned in the comment above.

Comment: `string_view` has another constructor that accepts a `count` as input, eg: `string_view str_v{ foo, sizeof(foo) };`

Comment: @RemyLebeau Yes, definitely, but I decided not to mention it.